# JQuery 3.3.0 slideDown() Mobile Jumpback to display none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following JQ Code

```js
var $body = $('body'),
  $accordion = $body.find('[data-accordion]'),
  $heading = $accordion.find('[data-accordion="heading"]'),
  $content = $accordion.find('[data-accordion="content"]');

$heading.click(function(e) {

  if (!($(this).hasClass('open'))) {
    $(this).addClass('open');
    $(this).next().slideDown(300);
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('open');
    $(this).next().slideUp(300);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="accordion" data-tabs="" data-accordion="">
    <div class="accordion--inner">
      <div class="accordion--headline open" data-accordion="heading"><span>Status</span></div>
      <div class="accordion--content" data-accordion="content" style="display: none;">
        <ul class="list--clear">
          <li class="search-filter-subcontent__element" itemprop="name">
            <input class="form__field--checkbox" id="checkbox7" type="checkbox" value="">
            <label class="form__field--label" for="checkbox7"><span>Checkbox</span></label>
          </li>
          <li class="search-filter-subcontent__element" itemprop="name">
            <input class="form__field--checkbox" id="checkbox8" type="checkbox" value="">
            <label class="form__field--label" for="checkbox8"><span>Checkbox</span></label>
          </li>
          <li class="search-filter-subcontent__element" itemprop="name">
            <input class="form__field--checkbox" id="checkbox9" type="checkbox" value="">
            <label class="form__field--label" for="checkbox9"><span>Checkbox</span></label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And on Desktop is everything fine but if I test this on a mobil device or with chrome develop tool the dropdown slides down and when its completed the inline display style jumps back to display: none. I don't realy know what to do.

Comment: For me it's good, I checked with `chrome develop tool`

Comment: You might experience problems with double triggered clicks. You add/remove the open class and then animate for 0.3 seconds. If you double click, the open class is already there before the animation ends, causing it to close without animation. You could try to block the click event while in animation. Set an "inanimation" class before the slide functions and remove it in the slide functions complete callback.

Comment: @Pedram yeah in here its also ok for me but not ob my webpage

Comment: @user3154108 I don't think so because the .open class is still there. I have to click one more time to discard the class and the third click adds again the open class and it happens the same like at the first click

Comment: @MrTilllus try to see if other click events are bound to your elements on the webpage, maybe some other script interferes. I don't know about Chrome, but Firefox shows you the events on an element in the DOM Inspector.

Comment: @user3154108 Ok now one day later it workseverything fine, but i doesen't change anything